# email functionality is not working fine

Tags: iphone

I have used the `MFMailComposeViewController` for sending the email in my code. I have also used the reachability code to check the internet connection. Internet connection is working fine. Whenever I used to send a mail from my code I got the message that email has been sent. But I didn't get any mail. There is no email which is sending from the app. I don't what is the reason behind this. If someone know how to get rid of this problem please provide me some solution.

```
-(void)sendemail
{
    emailBody = @"";
    mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mail setSubject:@"Report"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [mail addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"licence.png"];
    NSMutableString *breakline = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [breakline appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<br>"]];
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"m.garg@ldh.01s.in"]; 
    [mail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",@"Name: ",namestr,breakline,@"Address: ", addresstr,breakline,@"Landmark: ",landmarkstr,breakline,@"City: ", citystr,breakline,@"State: ", statestr,breakline,@"PIN: ", pinstr,breakline,@"Contact No: ",phonestr,breakline,@"Licence:",licencestr,breakline,@"Email Id", emailstr];
    [mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
    if (mail != nil) {
        [self presentModalViewController: mail animated: YES];
        [mail release];
    }
}
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: Please check whether `data` has valid data.

Comment: Also check whether we can send mail by using `if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] )`

Answer (score 0):

Simply try something like this:

```
 if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"123@abc.com.pk"]];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@""];
[controller setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO]; 
if (controller) [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
}
```

and don't forget to add the following delegate method for returning to your app:

```
 - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                    error:(NSError*)error;
{
if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
    NSLog(@"It's away!");
}
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

I wonder if your "to recipients" array is being freed before the email got sent.

Are your recipent emails showing in the "Send To" field when the mail composer view controller appears ?